How to add a subscription filter based on label ids
I'm integrating into the pub/sub capabilities in order to get copies of sent and received emails from users in my G-Suite. I'm quickly realizing that this can get chatty. It seems like every movement of anything in the inbox triggers a history event, which I can see useful in some circumstances, but in this case, I really only care about those 2 events (An email being sent or received).
In order to cut down on my processing, I saw where I can add a subscription filter, however I'm struggling to find where all of my options are. Ideally, I'd love to filter based on the label id, because then I could create a filter where the label id must be either "SENT" or "INBOX".
Does anybody happen to be able to guide me on this?


It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Gmail filtering for Cloud Pub/Sub messages is not set up in the subcription, it is set up when connecting Gmail push notifications to Cloud Pub/Sub. You set the labelIds and labelFilterBehavior when you specify the topicName. As shown in that documentation, a sample POST request would be:
POST "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch"
Content-type: application/json

{
  topicName: "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic",
  labelIds: ["INBOX"],
  labelFilterBehavior: "INCLUDE",
}

The Pub/Sub message produced by the Gmail push notifications does not include any attributes, so it is not possible to filter based on labels via Pub/Sub subscription-based filters.
